# Error on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am working on Eclipse Juno Tomcat server 5.5 by using JSP programming language. Suddenly, I got an error on a program from the system. It's shows `HTTP Status 404` and the description is `The requested resource is not available`. In this case, problem occurs from my PC only whether for the other PC, there was no problem. So, I don't think that the error is caused from my codes or database. Therefore, it was a pleasure if someone can give some explanation an advice on how to solve this problem. Thank you very much...

Comment: It looks like Eclipse incorrectly deploys or redeploys your application that sometimes happens. Open the server console in eclipse and remove the context, try 'Run on server' again. Also in some cases it doesn't work until you deploy another application (remove the original) and then run again your application. The alternative solution is to delete files in your eclipse tomcat directories, that is very hard to explain because it depends on your installation.

Comment: thank you for the asnwer,but can you put your answer in answer section.I'm going to vote up for gaining rep..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Eclipse incorrectly deploys or redeploys your application that sometimes happens. Open the server console in eclipse and remove the context, try 'Run on server' again. Also in some cases it doesn't work until you deploy another application (remove the original) and then run again your application. The alternative solution is to delete files in your eclipse tomcat directories, that is very hard to explain because it depends on your installation.